# How to add Owners to an Azure Active Directory Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am registering AAD Applications through the following code

```
ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await GetAppTokenAsync());

            Application application = new Application()
            {
                AvailableToOtherTenants = false,
                DisplayName = appName,
                ErrorUrl = null,
                GroupMembershipClaims = null,
                Homepage = "http://"+appName,
                IdentifierUris = new List<string>() { "https://"+appName }, 
                KeyCredentials = new List<KeyCredential>(),
                KnownClientApplications = new List<Guid>(),
                LogoutUrl = null,
                Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow = false,
                Oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching = false,
                Oauth2Permissions = new List<OAuth2Permission>(),
                Oauth2RequirePostResponse = false,
                // PasswordCredentials = new List<PasswordCredential>(),
                PasswordCredentials = new List<PasswordCredential>(),
                PublicClient = false,
                ReplyUrls = new List<string>(),
                // RequiredResourceAccess = new List<RequiredResourceAccess>(),
                RequiredResourceAccess = new List<RequiredResourceAccess>(),
                SamlMetadataUrl = null,
                ExtensionProperties = new List<ExtensionProperty>(),
                Manager = null,
                ObjectType = "Application",
                DeletionTimestamp = null,
                CreatedOnBehalfOf = null,
                CreatedObjects = new List<DirectoryObject>(),
                DirectReports = new List<DirectoryObject>(),
                Members = new List<DirectoryObject>(),
                MemberOf = new List<DirectoryObject>(),
                Owners = new List<DirectoryObject>(),
                OwnedObjects = new List<DirectoryObject>(),
                Policies = new List<DirectoryObject>()
            };
```

I also have an object of type Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User which contains all the information of a User that I want to add as owner of the application.

How can I do that?

The way I was trying that is by doing this

```
activeDirectoryClient.Applications.AddApplicationAsync(application).Wait();

            ServicePrincipal newServicePrincpal = new ServicePrincipal();
            if (application != null)
            {
                newServicePrincpal.DisplayName = application.DisplayName;
                newServicePrincpal.AccountEnabled = true;
                newServicePrincpal.AppId = application.AppId;
                newServicePrincpal.Owners.Add(user);

                try
                {
                    activeDirectoryClient.ServicePrincipals.AddServicePrincipalAsync(newServicePrincpal).Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
```

But when I navigate to the application manually in the Azure Portal, the only owner that appears is my own account and not also the other account I got in the **user** variable

Any idea how to add other owners to the application?

Comment: Have you fixed this issue now? Please feel free to let me know if you still have the problem about this issue.

Comment: Actually I haven't been able to fix this yet. Could you provide a sample of the GraphHelper class?

Comment: It just a very simple class to help construct the `ActiveDirectoryClient` class, I have append it to the post. Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this issue too. The root cause for this issue is that the Azure AD Graph library doesn't provide the owner info when it try to create the service principal.

If you want to add the owner for the **service principal**, you can use code below after you creating the service principal:

```
var activeDirectoryClient = GraphHelper.CreateGraphClient();
var sp = (ServicePrincipal)activeDirectoryClient.ServicePrincipals.GetByObjectId("4af8365b-1b49-481c-8c47-7b3fab5611fc").ExecuteAsync().Result;
var user = new Users().GetUserByUserName(activeDirectoryClient, "user2@adfei.onmicrosoft.com").Result;
sp.Owners.Add(user);
sp.UpdateAsync();
```

And if you want to add the owner of **application**, here is the code for you reference:

```
var activeDirectoryClient = GraphHelper.CreateGraphClient();
var app = (Application)activeDirectoryClient.Applications.GetByObjectId("bd87934b-dd4f-446a-a025-7675d1b2464a").ExecuteAsync().Result;
var user = new Users().GetUserByUserName(activeDirectoryClient, "user2@adfei.onmicrosoft.com").Result;
app.Owners.Add(user);
app.UpdateAsync();
```

More detail about the difference between application and service principal please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects).

And if you want the Graph client library to support adding the owner when creating the them, you can try to submit the feedback from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

### Update

```
public static ActiveDirectoryClient CreateGraphClient()
{
    string accessToken = "";
    string tenantId= "";
    string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

    Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
    Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);

    ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await Task.FromResult(accessToken));

    return activeDirectoryClient;
}
```

Add a runalbe code sample to add an owner for the service principal:
https://github.com/VitorX/AddServicePrincipalWithOwner

### Update2

After you run the code sample in the above, you could capture the result using the **Fiddler** like below. And we can get the object id of service principal via the response of creating the service principal:
[image]

Then we can check the owners of principals via the REST like figure below:[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Couple of questions though.
Where is the GraphHelper class coming from? Also, where did you get your ObjectId from? I took mine from the Application that was created and then I got the following exception: "Resource '56598b8b-5df8-4ab7-abdf-c0e4b54ca1e2' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present." That resource is the ObjectId of my Application.

Comment: The `GraphHelper` is a custom class to help to create the `ActiveDirectoryClient` class. When creating the  **application** or **service principal**, we can assign the **objectid** for them. Then we can use this objectId to get/update the object. Please note it is the **objectId** instead of the **appid**. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that class. However, whenever I call var app = (Application)activeDirectoryClient.Applications.GetByObjectId(objectId).ExecuteAsync().Result it hangs there and it never returns...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It seems that the object was not able to set when create the service principal. We can find the service principal using the **DisplayName** created before. And I have upload a demo code sample to [here](https://github.com/VitorX/AddServicePrincipalWithOwner). Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: I tried your code and while the application gets created successfully, the user is not being added as owner... I wonder if that could be a settings thing in Azure?

Comment: The code will create the owners for the **service principal**, you can check the owners via [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) using the request like `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{servicePrincipalsId}/owners`. This owners doesn't show up on the portal at present. Would you mind let me if there is other problem when you add the owner for the service principal?

Comment: I don't know what ID I should put for servicePrincipalsId but I took the AppId from the ServicePrincipals object. However, in the Graph explorer it returns an error. Also, I logged into Azure with the account that I added as owner and if i try to add a new owner in the application that was created. It tells me that I don't have enough privileges to do so. With that being said, I wasn't able to add an owner using your code. Are you able to add other owners from the account you added as owner?

Comment: That the **objectId** of the principal. The **objectId** we set for the principal will not be successfully, the server will assign this value instead of using the value we assigned. You can also check the **objectid** using Fiddler to capture the response for this request. I will update the detail in the post with some figures and please feel free to let me know if you still have the problem.

Comment: Fei Xue, I came back to this problem and even using your solution and looking into Fiddler, I wasn't able to see the newly added owner. I am wondering whether the AccessToken that I am generating has anything to do with it. Can you please share your function that generates an AccessToken?